# CSS overlay menu not working in firefox

Tags: javascript, html, css, firefox, overlays

I have this code

style.css

```
.row {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 22px;
    width: 100%;
    background: black;
    color: white;
    padding: 0px;
}

.content {
    margin-top: 22px;
    padding: 10px;
}

div.navigation span.left {
  float: left;
  text-align: left;
  font-weight: bold;
  width: 49%;
  }

div.navigation span.right {
  float: right;
  text-align: right;
  font-weight: bold;
  width: 49%;
  }

.menu {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background: black;
    color: white;
    padding: 10px;
opacity:0.9;
display: ;
}
```

navigation.htm

```
<html>
<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
http-equiv="content-type">
<title>Home</title>
<link rel="StyleSheet" href="style.css" type="text/css">
<script type="text/javascript">
function dispHandle(obj)
{
if (obj.style.display == "none")
obj.style.display = "";
else
obj.style.display = "none";
}

</script>
</head>
<body onload="dispHandle(uni);">
<div class="navigation">
<div id="container" style="width: 100%;">
<div class="row"> <span class="left"><a onmouseover="dispHandle(uni)">Activities</a><img
style="width: 18px; height: 18px;" alt="" src="images/void.png"></span>
<span style="font-weight: bold;" class="right"><img
style="width: 18px; height: 18px;" alt="" src="images/volume.png"><img
style="width: 18px; height: 18px;" alt="" src="images/bluetooth.png"><img
style="width: 18px; height: 18px;" alt="" src="images/wireless.png"><img
style="width: 26px; height: 18px; font-style: italic;" alt=""
src="images/battery.png"><iframe
src="http://free.timeanddate.com/clock/i2vrnsgh/fcfff/tct/pct/ftb"
allowtransparency="true" frameborder="0" height="18" width="86"></iframe><img
style="width: 18px; height: 18px;" alt="" src="images/user.png">Demi
Lovato&nbsp;</span>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div id="uni">
<div style="text-align: center;" class="menu"> <br>
<img onclick="dispHandle(uni)"
style="border: 0px solid ; width: 48px; height: 48px;" alt=""
    src="http://demilovato.sourceforge.net/images/close.png"><br>
<br>
<div align="center">
<table style="text-align: left; width: 410px; height: 268px;" border="1"
cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td style="vertical-align: top; text-align: center;"><a
href="index.htm"><img
style="border: 0px solid ; width: 48px; height: 48px;" alt=""
src="images/Home.png"></a><br>
Home<br>
</td>
<td style="vertical-align: top; text-align: center;"><a
href="Downloads.htm"><img
style="border: 0px solid ; width: 48px; height: 48px;" alt=""
src="images/Downloads.png"></a><br>
Downloads<br>
</td>
<td style="vertical-align: top; text-align: center;"><a
href="Screenshots.htm"><img
style="border: 0px solid ; width: 48px; height: 48px;" alt=""
src="images/Screenshots.png"></a><br>
Screenshots<br>
</td>
<td style="vertical-align: top; text-align: center;"><a
href="Links.htm"><img
style="border: 0px solid ; width: 48px; height: 48px;" alt=""
src="images/Links.png"></a><br>
Links<br>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="vertical-align: top; text-align: center;"><a
href="FAQ.htm"><img
style="border: 0px solid ; width: 48px; height: 48px;" alt=""
src="images/FAQ.png"></a><br>
FAQ<br>
</td>
<td style="vertical-align: top; text-align: center;"><a
href="Contact.htm"><img
style="border: 0px solid ; width: 48px; height: 48px;" alt=""
src="images/Contact.png"></a><br>
Contact<br>
</td>
<td style="vertical-align: top; text-align: center;"><a
href="About.htm"><img
style="border: 0px solid ; width: 48px; height: 48px;" alt=""
src="images/About.png"></a><br>
About<br>
</td>
<td style="vertical-align: top;"><br>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<br>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Its suppose to be able to mouse over Activities and it shows a full screen css menu
and then close by clicking the X I do this by a show hide javascipt function.
Two problems are when I load it in firefox it does not work yet it works in all other browsers I tried it in (Safari, Chrome, Rekonq)
Also how can I hide it by default instead of onload?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example solution here: http://jsfiddle.net/msZVY/3/

As told in the Firefox console, Firefox doesn't know what "uni" is.  The function `dispHandle(uni)` says "Execute dsipHandle function with the parameter having object uni".  uni is not defined.

I'm not sure why Safari/Chrome is able to be "smarter" and see that uni is the id of an element.  (perhaps someone else can enlighten me)  But for Firefox you should explicitly state this using:

```
function dispHandle(id)
{
  obj = document.getElementById(id);  //define obj using the id
  if (obj.style.display == "none")
    obj.style.display = "block";
  else
    obj.style.display = "none";
}
```

In your inline javascript you should put uni in quotes.  `onmouseover="dispHandle('uni')"` instead of `onmouseover="dispHandle(uni)"`

To answer your other question about an alternative way to hide it besides onload, you can do it with regular css:

```
#uni{display:none}
```

In your above function I also changed it from `obj.style.display = "";` to `obj.style.display = "block";`  as this will explicitly change it in the stylesheet to div's default block display, overwriting your style.css

Comment: Nice, I like your design idea.  Glad I could help.

Comment: Thanks I based it off the GNOME desktop environment http://gnome.org and I:m glad you could help because I just started web programming 5 days ago and I don:t really know much what I am doing.